# Get admob Id remotely

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, admob

I have an application I made using android studio. As of the moment, the admob ids are defined in the `strings.xml` file. However, I want to make the app get the admob ids from either my server or from firebase as I want to be able to change them remotely should any problems occur. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Either you can load Ads From Firebase Using [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android)

or you Can Use the Firebase database. Refer this Sample Project from my Github
[Load Ads From Firebse](https://github.com/cyberworldtechnologies/LoadAdsFromFirebase)

[image: Using Database]

Comment: Can you show how to use it? We should to provide the AppId in the manifest file, how to do it dynamically?

Comment: @dyno-cris Unfortunately we can't do anything dynamically in the Manifest file. you have to hard code the strings.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it programmatically.**

**Layout**

From your layout file, add `AdView`:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/adView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"
   ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Retrieving Ad Unit Id**

- You need to do network calls either on your splash screen or main activity to retrieve your Ad Unit Id/s
- You can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for doing such http request calls from your web server
- If you choose Firebase, you can use their 
  [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/realtime/database%E2%80%8E)

**Setting Ad Unit Id**

In Java

```java
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"); // Set ad unit id
```

In Kotlin

```
val adView = AdView(this)
adView.adSize = AdSize.BANNER
adView.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" // Set ad unit id
```

**Additional**

Depending on your persistent storage implementation, here's a one liner way of saving the Ad Unit Id using `SharedPreferences`

```java
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("MY_AD_UNIT_ID", "YOUR_AD_UNIT_VALUE").apply();
```

Here's how you will retrieve it

```java
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("MY_AD_UNIT_ID", "DEFAULT_STRING_IF_NOTHING_WAS_FOUND");
```

Where `context` is your Context.

**Read more:**

- https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Comment: At the moment it is currently like that however I want the app to get the admob Id from my web server or from firebase. Any idea as to how I would do that?

Comment: Hi @MohammedSalaam, mind if I ask if you happen to have setup your web server already?

Comment: I have a php file on my web server with my admob id on it. I was wondering if I could somehow send a get request to the server, get the admob id, and save it. But I dont really know how to do this on app startup?

Comment: Let me confirm, are you knowledgeable in parsing JSON responses in the mobile app? If so, you can invoke such API request on your splash screen. From there, you can retrieve the the Ad Unit Id, afterwards you can save it using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). In that way, you can just retrieve it from the view layers that need the Ad Unit Id.

Comment: Can I send a get request using android volley in the splash screen and get the admob is as a string? If so, how would I use this id in my other classes?

Comment: Yes, you surely can. I have added a simple usage of `SharedPreferences`, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new [API that allows you to manage Firebase projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects#FirebaseProject) and get configuration data from them. This would be the most logical place to look up such configuration data programmatically.

I checked the [`projects.get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/get) and [`projects.getAdminConfig`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/getAdminSdkConfig), but haven't been able to find the ID you're looking for yet.

If that ID is indeed missing, it might be worth it to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).